# Incompatibility between validatorjs module and html5 validator?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, validation

I got an annoying problem in validating input fields using validatorjs module.

For the sake of clarity there's the input form image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcRng.png

I'm trying to validate every rule with validatorjs, there's the code (I'm using React).

First function: checkValidity --->

```
checkValidity() {
    let data = {
        From: this.state.start,
        To: this.state.end,
        Category: this.state.category,
        Age: this.state.age,
        ExtraDrivers: this.state.extraDrivers,
        EstimatedKm: this.state.estimatedKm
    };

    Validator.register('after', function (date, params, attribute){
        const momentEnd = moment(date);
        return moment(params).isBefore(momentEnd, 'day');
    });

    let rules = {
        From: ['required', 'regex:/([12]\\d{3}/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0[1-9]|[12]\\d|3[01]))/'],
        To: ['required', 'regex:/([12]\\d{3}/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/(0[1-9]|[12]\\d|3[01]))/', `after:${this.state.start}`],
        Category: 'required',
        Age: 'required|between:18,88',
        ExtraDrivers: 'required|between:0,10',
        EstimatedKm: 'required'
    };
    let validation = new Validator(data, rules, {
        required: ':attribute is mandatory',
        regex: ":attribute is not valid date format",
        after: "To should be after From",
        between: ":attribute should be between :min and :max"
    });
    return validation;
}
```

second function: submitHandler ---->

```
submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("SUBMITHANDLER");
    let validation = this.checkValidity();
    if (validation.passes()) {
        console.log("YOOOOOOOOOOO");
    }
    else {
        console.log("From has errors?: "+validation.errors.has('From'));
        console.log("To has errors?: "+validation.errors.has('To'));
        console.log("Category has errors?: "+validation.errors.has('Category'));
        console.log("Age has errors?: "+validation.errors.has('Age'));
        this.setState({
            reportMessage: validation.errors.first('From') ||
                validation.errors.first('To') ||
                validation.errors.first('Category') ||
                validation.errors.first('Age') ||
                validation.errors.first('ExtraDrivers')
        });
    }
}
```

Well, the problem is that validatorjs can catch validation errors for the first three Form.Control (in "validation.errors" array). This happen (I think, not sure at all) because when I force a validation error (for example) on the Age Form.Control it's been catched by HTML5 validator (don't know why) thanks to the "invalid" event. I noticed that if it happens the submit event will not be triggered, so the submitHandler callback function will not be called and my customized validation error message won't be displayed.

Images of what happens in browser:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2ffd.png ["From" custom error message]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2bQp.png ["To" custom error message]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIvIF.png ["Category" custom error message]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1p6ll.png ["Age" NOT custom error message (problem here)]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ebm6.png [logs from submitHandler callback]

I need the same behaviour of the first three input fields for the rest of them.
Thank you for your help!

P.S: here a stackblitz link to try it on your own

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zaho8x?file=index.js

P.S(2.0): [SOLVED] If you check the Age Form.Control component on line 122 (on stackblitz) you can see that there are min and max html validation keys. Removing them I solved. The same happens for extraDrivers input field.

```
<Form.Control name="age" type="number" value={this.state.age} min={18} max={88} placeholder={18} onChange={(ev) => this.changeHandler(ev.target.name, ev.target.value)}/>
```

Comment: Is it possible to create and share here a running codesandbox with a minimal and complete, reproducible example?

Comment: <https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zaho8x?file=index.js> Stackblitz

Comment: solved. I'll write the solution on the main post